# GoogleConnect.Fetch throws Unable to cast object error

Tags: c#, google-api

I am integrating the Google API into my project. I am using the following code to do so:

```
public void google()
    {

        GoogleConnect.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
            string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code.ToString());
            GoogleProfile profile = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleProfile>(json);
            //code for showing data on my page
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
        }

    }
    public class GoogleProfile
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

It runs when I click on the google button and shows data on the first instance but it throws the following error the second time I try it.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type '?1?'.

I also have a facebook and twitter button on the same screen but I doubt that it is causing the problem. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: which line exactly is it failing on?

Comment: string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code.ToString()); line no. 11. and that happens the second time i try to aloow access.

Comment: Figure out what code is then its not something that you can cast as a string.

Comment: thats the problem i can't go to definition of of google.fetch. on the first instance it sends the data and i am able to use it. not on the second

Comment: Is this a home grown library?  This isn't Googles official client library.

Comment: GoogleConnect.Fetch comes from the aspsnippet.google.dll file you are right. sorry should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have used this api you should used it place a clear button where you show profile 
**create button clear**

```
 protected void Clear(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleConnect.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: For those who don't know where it needs to be implemented, *The Clear method of the GoogleConnect class clears the current access token. Thus when some user logs out of the website, this method can be used to clear his current session.* Therefore on logout. [Login with Google Account API in ASP.Net and get Google Plus Profile details](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-Google-Account-API-in-ASPNet-and-get-Google-Plus-Profile-details.aspx)