# Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type '?2?.?3?.?5?'

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-oauth

I'm facing this error when calling Google login from my ASP.NET web page.

> This is the error which I'm facing when executing my code.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type '?2?.?3?.?5?'
```

I am integrating Google login to my web page using ASP.NET with C#.

My code is as follows:

```
page_load() {

        GoogleConnect.ClientId = "xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", "code");
            GoogleProfile profile = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleProfile>(json);
            Label1.Text = profile.Id;
            Label2.Text = profile.DisplayName;
            Label3.Text = profile.Emails.Find(email => email.Type == "account").Value;
            Image1.ImageUrl = profile.Image.Url;
            Button1.Visible = false;
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleConnect.Authorize("profile", "email");
    }

    public class GoogleProfile
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please! add more details(not Client Id and Client Secret), like what you have tried and research so far. If possible, configuration of Google cloud project and make sure to hide Client Id and secret.

Comment: And I think this question has already answered on this platform - [GoogleConnect.Fetch throws Unable to cast object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992739/googleconnect-fetch-throws-unable-to-cast-object-error/42994854)

Comment: @Utkarsh Dubey  ..Actually, I am making a blog where I want a comment by user who is signed via google api. Thats why I am using google api here, but when I click on the button my code carries me to the signin page and it shows the same error when I enter any username.

Comment: @user9444040 So above mentioned link didn't work for you?

Comment: you are right,  GoogleConnect.Fetch throws Unable to cast object error  ....it is answer of my question but I am nt understanding where Googleconnect.clear() is to be placed

Comment: *The Clear method of the GoogleConnect class clears the current access token. Thus when some user logs out of the website, this method can be used to clear his current session.* Therefore on logout. [Login with Google Account API in ASP.Net and get Google Plus Profile details](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-Google-Account-API-in-ASPNet-and-get-Google-Plus-Profile-details.aspx)